# Azure Logic App Step Fails with error "BadRequest. Http request failed: the timeout was reached"

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a long running azure function that an API call in a loop. I see that the logic step fails with the error "BadRequest. Http request failed: the timeout was reached" .
What could be the reason behind it and how can we resolve it?

Answer (score 5):

In Logic App HTTP Request Max Timeout is **120 sec**. so if your azure function response time is gether than 120 sec then this error will come..

[image]

[please find more details in this link related to limitation of azure logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config)